# How to get tweets using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, twitter, express

is there a way of getting twitter tweets on your own site using node.js. I tried some node.js modules but did not get how to achieve this.

Comment: Checkout ntwitter which has the Twitter API for tweets - https://github.com/AvianFlu/ntwitter

Comment: Tried this code :   twit.stream('statuses/sample', function(stream) {
    console.log('stream==========================twitter',stream);
    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('data=======================',data);
    });                                                                  Console doesn't show anything for data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may not even need to use node to do this. Twitter has a number of client-side widgets you can use to host your profile, tweets from a search, your favorites, or a list: https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets

Now, if you want to begin manipulating those tweets or display them in a custom fashion, then you'll want to use the nTwitter module as First Zero suggested.

Comment: Thanks for help. Yes i tried the search method of ntwitter which worked fine.But the problem is how can i get the tweets of a particular user dynamically i.e the user who is currently logged in to the system. Also stream.on() method is not working as it outputs nothing

Comment: You need to integrate the use of ntwitter with an oauth package like passport or everyauth. You'll need to create a simple oauth login system that allows the current user to grant your system oauth access (providing you with their key and token). You'll use the user's access key and token in conjunction with your application's access key and token (all 4 are required to start a user stream) to start your stream. At that point, all tweets your user would receive will go to your app.